# Filters Blogger posts on a specific page

Tags: html, xml, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

I come to you again. See my code.

I am trying to filter articles from a particular tag so that they only appear on a static page.

I can do this only on the homepage.

When I try to do the same on a specific page nothing appears.

Here is the code that works on the homepage.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "static_page"'>

<b:section id='posts-noticias'>

    <b:widget id='Blog2' locked='true' title='Blog Archive' type='Blog'>

    <b:includable id='main' var='top'>
       <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "static_page"'>
    <b:loop values='data:posts where (p=&gt; p.labels any (l=&gt; l.name == &quot; TAG &quot;)) take 6' var='post'>
      <b:include data='post' name='printPosts'/>
    </b:loop>
    <b:else/>
    <b:include data='post' name='printPosts'/>
  </b:if>
</b:includable>

    <b:includable id='printPosts' var='post'>

<div class='post hentry' style="background-color: #ffff00; border-width:1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #000000; height: 200px">
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:post.title'>
<h2 class='post-title entry-title'>
<b:if cond='data:post.link'>
<a expr:href='data:post.link'><data:post.title/></a>
<b:else/>
<b:if cond='data:post.url'>
<a expr:href='data:post.url'><data:post.title/></a>
<b:else/>
<data:post.title/>
</b:if>
</b:if>
</h2>
</b:if>
<b:else/>

</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
<div class='cutter'>
<b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'> 


</b:if>

<a expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:href='data:post.url' expr:title='data:post.title'>
<div class='Image thumb'>
<img expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:src='resizeImage(data:post.firstImageUrl, 200, "150:70")' expr:title='data:post.title'/>
</div>
</a>
</div>

</b:if></b:if>

<div class='post-body entry-content' expr:id='&quot;post-body-&quot; + data:post.id'>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>

</b:if>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
   <b:eval expr='snippet(data:post.body, {length: 100, links: false})'/>
</b:if>
</b:if>

</div>

</div>


</b:includable>
</b:widget>
</b:section>

</b:if>
```

The only change I made was to change the conditional Home to the static page.

Answer (score 0):

On single post pages and static pages, you can get only one post data via `data:posts` loop.

What you can do is to use Blogger JSON feed with JavaScript to get what you want.

For example: this code fetches the first six titles on your blog.

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<script>
  //<![CDATA[
    fetch('/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json&max-results=6')
    .then(response => response.json()).then(json => {
        let posts = json.feed.entry.map(e => `<h2>${e.title.$t}</h2>`);
        document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = posts.join('');
    });
  //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, I already knew I could do this with java / script, but I wanted to create a static page similar to wordpress and show articles from a tag on it, / search / label / does it but the blogger doesn't indexes these pages, so I thought I'd create a specific page with dynamic content on it.

Comment: @resumo, there is no page that search engines don't index, you just need the right configuration.

Comment: Hello, I happen to be using Blogger to post articles and the Search / label page is set in the googlewebmaster console to not index. in my searches google automatically blocks this page. It appears that Google penalizes the blog that changes these settings.

Comment: @resumo You might need to check your **robots.txt** file and change some rules to allow indexing labels page, however it's not a seo friendly choice.