# Change color by Blogger Tag

Tags: javascript, css, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

is there any way to change some blogger areas by tag?

Example, I'm on a page that has the tag cars, only this page would have as a few sections:

.body
.header

have a different color from other pages?

I got this script that changes the background color of the site every 12 hours, but it's still not what I'm looking for, what I would like was to change parts of the blog as the tag changed

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
    if (6 <= currentTime && currentTime < 12) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#1abc9c";
    } else if (12 <= currentTime && currentTime < 18) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#318fcb";
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#560256";
    }
//]]></script>
```

More information:

I know it is possible to use this code to make the changes happen, but the changes only happen on the label page, as the changes happen on all pages that have the car tag.

```html
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == "car"'>
   <style type='text/css'>
       body { background: #e2ad44 !important }
   </style>
</b:if>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "change some blogger areas by tag" ?

Comment: I would like to change the color of areas like: background, header,

As I found these codes that I posted in the question, I found it more interesting to change the color of the site according to the description to make the blog different.

For example, whenever someone has read an article about cars and this post has the tag cars the background color of the site is Blue, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet in the end of your question will work perfectly in labels page. In article page you need a similar code to check if post has a specific tag, so you need to add the next code within **main blog posts loop**:

```html
<!-- check if page type is article page & check if article has a "car" tag -->
<b:if cond='data:view.isPost and data:post.labels any (l => l.name == "car")'>
  <style>
    body { background: #e2ad44 }
  </style> 
</b:if>
```

Comment: I tried your code and unfortunately it didn't work.

I think there must be some way this works

Comment: Where did you insert it? it should be within **Blog** widget loop: `<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>.....</b:loop>`.

Comment: Finally, this time it worked, I added below <b: loop values = 'data: posts' var = 'post'>

Comment: You seem to understand these blogger codes well, could you help me with another question? if so, look at this question that I did some time ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925862/filters-blogger-posts-on-a-specific-page

Comment: As @Bassam mentioned, there's no another way to get posts in static page in Blogger.

Comment: I understand, coming back to the question of this page, the code worked well, would you add more than 1 tag in the conditional?

Example: (l => l.name == "car, nature, water, sun")

Comment: Sure, you can do that: `(l => l.name in ["car", "nature", "water", "sun"])`.

Comment: Thanks, one more question, the page containing search / label that are the blogger tags, would you have to apply SEO on it? I am trying to optimize this page but it seems that the blogger does not provide anything to do this, in worpress this is easier. would you have any idea how to make it google friendly?

Comment: Sorry I can't help you about that, open a new question with more info and I hope you got help.

Comment: How do I show it on every blog except for certain tags?

Comment: I have the same problem, I want to change the color just when all the posts have one especific tag  in all the posts if not the color is other. How can I do that ?