# Change the color of the search results background in blogger and the same tag posts

Tags: blogger, blogger-dynamic-views, google-blogger-api

Good night people!
I am creating a blog on blogger and I would like to put the background color according to the tag.
For example: when I search for a tag eg: `Books` all the posts that contain this tag will appear and the posts that contain this tag will appear with the blue background. When I open a post that has the tag `Books` this post also has to have the blue blog background.
I tried to find a similar question in the stackoverflow in English but the code didn't work here is the link [Change color by Blogger Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59366598/change-color-by-blogger-tag)

But when I put this code on the blogger and with the tags with their proper colors, it always stays with the last color set and not one for each tag as I wanted ...
And when there is no tag he is putting the color in the same way as if he did not have an `if`.

The blogger was supposed to stay on top of the color of each navigation button on the side.

[image]

When I put the code the main page is the color that was supposed to be only when all posts included the tag I'm looking for.

This is the main page
[image]

**Updated:**
The menu code is the following:

```
<!-- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_dropdown -->



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/fontawesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/solid.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/brands.min.css"/>











<!doctype html>


<style>
#mySidenav a {
  position: fixed;
  left: -230px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 270px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

#mySidenav a:hover {
  left: 0;
}


#search {
  top: 40px;
  background-color: #FFBA99;
}

#home {
  top: 100px;
  background-color: #BA2D26;
}
#about {
  top: 160px;
  background-color: #0055A5;
}

#blog {
  top: 220px;
  background-color: #5F6BB0;
}

#projects {
  top: 280px;
  background-color: #158DA9;
}

#contact {
  top: 340px;
  background-color: #8F2054;
}
#matematica{
  top:400px;
  background-color:#B1BB36;
}



#sheatsheet{
  top:460px;
  background-color:#B80c00;
}

#postsPolulares{
  top:520px;
  background-color:#420085;
}

#arquivos{
  top:580px;
  background-color:#963c00;
}

#contato{
  top:640px;
  background-color:#8a0a83;
}

#sobre{
  top:700px;
  background-color:#006b54;
}
#repositorio{
    top:760px;
  background-color:#000000;
}
#calendario{
    top:820px;
  background-color:#0F89BA;
}

#media{
    top:880px;
  background-color:#EC7650;
}

#books{
    top:940px;
  background-color:#49497F;
}




#rss{
  top:1000px;
  background-color:#D38094;
}


a{
text-align: right;
}


/* Novo estilo*/
*{box-sizing: border-box}

/* Set height of body and the document to 100% */
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Style tab links */
.tablink {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 25%;
}

.tablink:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

/* Style the tab content (and add height:100% for full page content) */
.tabcontent {
  color: white;
  display: none;
  padding: 100px 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

#Search {background-color: #FFBA99;}
#Home {background-color: #BA2D26;}
#About {background-color: #0055A5;}
#Blog {background-color: #5F6BB0;}
#Projects {background-color: #158DA9;}
#Contact {background-color: #8F2054;}
#Matematica {background-color:#B1BB36;}
#Sheatsheet  {background-color:#B80c00;}
#PostsPolulares {background-color:#420085;}
#Arquivos {background-color:#963c00;}
#Contato {background-color:#8a0a83;}
#Sobre {background-color:#006b54;}
#Repositorio {background-color:#000000;}
#Calendario {background-color:#0F89BA;}
#Media {background-color:#EC7650;}
#Books {background-color:#49497F;}
#Rss {background-color:#D38094;}
/*#News {background-color: green;}
#Contact {background-color: blue;}
#About {background-color: orange;}*/


/*FIm DO NOVO ESTILO*/


</style>




<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="https://www.steamizando.com/p/busca.html" id="search" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Search', this, '#FFBA99')">Pesquisar <i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.steamizando.com/p/home.html" id="home" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Home', this, '#BA2D26')">Home <i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.steamizando.com/p/ciencia.html" id="about" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this, '#0055A5')"> Ciência <i class="fas fa-microscope"></i> </a>
  <a href="https://www.steamizando.com/p/tecnologia.html" id="blog" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Blog', this, '#5F6BB0')"> Tecnologia  <i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.steamizando.com/p/engenharia.html" id="projects" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Projects', this, '#158DA9')"> Engenharia <i class="fas fa-tools"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.steamizando.com/p/artes.html" id="contact" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Contact', this, '#8F2054')"> Artes  <i class="fas fa-palette"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.steamizando.com/search/label/Matematica" id="matematica" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Matematica', this, '#B1BB36')"> Matematica <i class="fas fa-square-root-alt"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.steamizando.com/p/cheatsheet.html" id="sheatsheet" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Sheatsheet', this, '#b80c00')" >Sheatsheet <i class="fas fa-table"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.steamizando.com/p/populares.html" id="postsPolulares" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('PostsPolulares', this, '#420085')" > Polulares <i class="fas fa-fire"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.steamizando.com/p/arquivos.html" id="arquivos" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Arquivos', this, '#963c00')" >Arquivos <i class="fas fa-folder"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.steamizando.com/p/contato.html" id="contato" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Contato', this, '#8a0a83')" >Contato <i class="fas fa-at"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.steamizando.com/p/sobre.html" id="sobre" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Sobre', this, '#006b54')" >Sobre <i class="fas fa-address-card"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.steamizando.com/p/repositorio.html" id="repositorio" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Repositorio', this, '#000000')" >Repositorio <i class="fab fa-github-alt"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.steamizando.com/p/calendario.html" id="calendario" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Calendario', this, '#0F89BA')" >Calendario <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.steamizando.com/p/media.html" id="media" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Media', this, '#EC7650')">Media <i class="fas fa-photo-video"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.steamizando.com/p/livros.html" id="books" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Books', this, '#49497F')"> Books <i class="fas fa-book"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.steamizando.com/p/rss.html#" id="rss" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Rss', this, '#D38094')" >Rss  <i class="fas fa-rss"></i></a>
</div>

<!-- <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this, '#0055A5')">Home</button> -->
<div id="Search" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>
<div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<div id="About" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<div id="Blog" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<div id="Projects" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<div id="Contact" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<div id="Matematica" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>



<div id="Sheatsheet" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>


<div id="PostsPolulares" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<div id="Sheatsheet" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<div id="Arquivos" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<div id="Contato" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<div id="Repositorio" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<div id="Sobre" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<div id="Media" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<div id="Calendario" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<div id="Books" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>
<div id="Rss" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>




<script>
function openPage(pageName,elmnt,color) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>


</!doctype>
```

I've putted it in the script gadget in the blogger. But part of the code above doesn't appears there anymore when I open the gadget to edit it.
But the issue that I'm facing is  the following, for each Tab would be a searh link to a label like [enter link description here](https://www.steamizando.com/search/label/matematica). So I would like to click in the tab and all the posts that have the label `matematica` will apper in  a background with the same color of the tab. And the same thing will happen to all other tabs. But when the main page there are  all the posts, that is, when the colection of the posts (the union operation above the tags) the background should be white.

The code to change the background  is the following:

```
<script>
function openPage(pageName,elmnt,color) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

The one that I've found in [Change color by Blogger Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59366598/change-color-by-blogger-tag)

I think that the problem is in this part of the code:

```
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: please update the question with the code you are using

Comment: The test is in the tag `matematica` which is the only tag test, I've added more tags  but is just for testing

Answer (score 0):

I have solved part of the problem  replacing the `tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = color;` to `document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;`
But it just changed the color for in the moment of the click.
I would like it that the background could stay with color until I click into another tab.
If someone knows how to do it :)
Thanks a lot